# Hover Not working after keeping DIV Element position to Sticky

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have 5 DIV elements, In those five, I have assigned position:sticky and top:0 to last but in one element which is Footer. After assigning position:sticky, the hover is not working to the child elements.

```css
    .works {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  justify-content: space-between;
  padding-left: 10rem;
  padding-right: 10rem;
  margin-bottom: 10rem;
}
.footer {
          display: flex;
          justify-content: center;
          align-items: center;
          z-index: -1;
          width: 100vw;
          height: 100vh;
          position: sticky;
          top: 0;
        }
        
        .s-i:hover {
          cursor: none;
          color: var(--primary-yellow);
        }
```

```html
<div className="works">
        <div className="project p-1">
            <Link style={{cursor:"none"}} to="/project1">
                <img className="project-image first-p" src={covac} alt="" />
            </Link>
        </div>
        
        <div className="project p-2">
            <Link style={{cursor:"none"}} to="/project2">
                <img className="project-image second-p" src={rogalik} alt="" />
            </Link>
        </div>
    
        <div className="project p-3">
            <Link style={{cursor:"none"}} to="/project3">
                <img className="project-image third-p" src={mia} alt="" />
            </Link>
        </div>
    
    </div>
    
    
    <div className="footer">
        <div className="social">
            <a href="https://twitter.com/nsarathsunny" className="s-i twitter"> <p className="t-text">Twitter</p> <span className="bordert"></span></a>
            <a href="https://twitter.com/nsarathsunny" className="s-i behance"> <p>Behance</p> <span className="borderb"></span></a>
            <a href="https://twitter.com/nsarathsunny" className="s-i linkedin"> <p>LinkedIn</p> <span className="borderl"></span></a>
            <a href="https://twitter.com/nsarathsunny" className="s-i insta"> <p>Instagram</p> <span className="borderi"></span></a>
            <a href="https://twitter.com/nsarathsunny" className="s-i mail"> <p> Mail</p> <span className="borderm"></span></a>
        </div>         
    </div>
    
    <div className="contact-pager">
        <Contact/>
    </div>
```

I tried using

```
@media(hover:hover){ 
.s-i:hover {
      cursor: none;
      color: var(--primary-yellow);
}}
```

I tried GSAP as well, but no luck with that also.

Comment: Hi. Please add your code as actual code, not as images. Best would be to add a runnable snippet so we can have a proper look at whats going on.

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/errors when asking a question](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551), but provide a proper [mre] of your issue instead.

Comment: It is my homepage of my portfolio website, so it's a long code. That is why I kept snippet.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because you set `.footer z-index` to `-1` and `.works` overwrite it, so I set the `z-index` to `1` and it works fine now

```css
.works {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  justify-content: space-between;
  padding-left: 10rem;
  padding-right: 10rem;
  margin-bottom: 10rem;
}
.footer {
          display: flex;
          justify-content: center;
          align-items: center;
          z-index: 1;
          width: 100vw;
          height: 100vh;
          position: sticky;
          top: 0;
        }
        
.s-i:hover {
     cursor: none;
     color: yellow;
}
```

```html
<div class="works">
        <div class="project p-1">
            <Link style={{cursor:"none"}} to="/project1">
                <img class="project-image first-p" src={covac} alt="" />
            </Link>
        </div>
        
        <div class="project p-2">
            <Link style={{cursor:"none"}} to="/project2">
                <img class="project-image second-p" src={rogalik} alt="" />
            </Link>
        </div>
    
        <div class="project p-3">
            <Link style={{cursor:"none"}} to="/project3">
                <img class="project-image third-p" src={mia} alt="" />
            </Link>
        </div>
    
    </div>
    
    
    <div class="footer">
        <div class="social">
            <a href="https://twitter.com/nsarathsunny" class="s-i twitter"> <p class="t-text">Twitter</p> <span class="bordert"></span></a>
            <a href="https://twitter.com/nsarathsunny" class="s-i behance"> <p>Behance</p> <span class="borderb"></span></a>
            <a href="https://twitter.com/nsarathsunny" class="s-i linkedin"> <p>LinkedIn</p> <span class="borderl"></span></a>
            <a href="https://twitter.com/nsarathsunny" class="s-i insta"> <p>Instagram</p> <span class="borderi"></span></a>
            <a href="https://twitter.com/nsarathsunny" class="s-i mail"> <p> Mail</p> <span class="borderm"></span></a>
        </div>         
    </div>
    
    <div className="contact-pager">
        <Contact/>
    </div>
```